# v-on:change.native doesn't bind in the parent component: Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component with checkbox input:

```
<template>
    <input id='one' type='checkbox' v-on:change.native="$emit('change')" />
</template>
```

I am using this component in another component:

```
<template>
....
    <Checkbox v-on:change="change" />
....
</template>
<script>
    import Checkbox from './components/Checkbox.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            Checkbox
        },
        methods: {
            change: function (e) { 
                console.log(e);
        },
    }
</script>
```

What I want is to attach parent component method, which must point to children component event. 
The problem is that this `change` event doesn't trigger when checkbox is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `input` event for checkboxes. I'd also recommend using [v-on="$listeners"](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) in the `Checkbox` component unless you really need to name the event `'change'`.

*Checkbox.vue*

```
<template>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    v-on="$listeners"
  >
</template>
```

*index.vue*

```
<template>
  <Checkbox @input="input" />
</template>

<script>
import Checkbox from '~/components/Checkbox.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Checkbox,
  },
  methods: {
    input(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`.native` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) is used *on components*, not on native widgets.

> There may be times when you want to listen directly to a native event
> on the root element of a component. In these cases, you can use the
> .native modifier for v-on

You could use `.native` in the outer binding to catch the `change` event bubbling from the inside (because native events generally bubble, while Vue events do not), *or* you could use non-`.native` events in both the inner and outer components to do your own bubbling.

The snippet below does both:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    change() {
      console.log("Native change");
    },
    change2() {
      console.log("Non-native");
    }
  },
  components: {
    myCheckbox: {
      template: '#inner-template'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<template id="inner-template">
    <input id='one' type='checkbox' v-on:change="$emit('change')" />
</template>
<div id="app">
  <my-checkbox v-on:change.native="change" @change="change2"></my-checkbox>
</div>
```